# my thread does not see windows Form components

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, c++-cli

I'm making a windows form application that uses threads, the threads is running and it works, but I want my thread to access the form components.
like BtnMain that is not seen inside the thread function.
how can I solve this?, here is my code

```
#pragma once

namespace winAppSocket {
struct struttura{
char c;
int num;
} mystruct;

UINT  ServerThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
printf("Starting up TCP server\r\n");
SOCKET server;
WSADATA wsaData;
sockaddr_in local;
int wsaret=WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData);
if(wsaret!=0)
{
    return 0;
}
local.sin_family=AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=INADDR_ANY;
local.sin_port=htons((u_short)20248);
server=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(server==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    return 0;
}
if(bind(server,(sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))!=0)
{
    return 0;
}
if(listen(server,10)!=0)
{
    return 0;
}
SOCKET client;
sockaddr_in from;
int fromlen=sizeof(from);
int buffer;
char buff;
while(true)
{
    client=accept(server,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);
    //printf("pppp\n");
    //con la struct
    int numByte=recv(client,(char*) &mystruct, (int) sizeof(mystruct), 0);

    //printf("%c\t%d\n", mystruct.c, mystruct.num);
    //ricevere un char funziona
    //int numByte=recv(client, &buff, (int) sizeof(buff), 0);
    //printf("%c\t%d\n", buff, numByte);
    //int numByte=recv(client, buffer, (int) strlen(buffer), 0);
    //questo funziona
    //int numByte=recv(client, (char*)&buffer, (int) sizeof(buffer), 0);
    //printf("%d\t%d\n", buffer, numByte);
    //printf("Connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr));
    closesocket(client);

}
closesocket(server);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;


/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
///
/// WARNING: If you change the name of this class, you will need to change the
///          'Resource File Name' property for the managed resource compiler tool
///          associated with all .resx files this class depends on.  Otherwise,
///          the designers will not be able to interact properly with localized
///          resources associated with this form.
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  BtnMain;

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->BtnMain = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // BtnMain
        // 
        this->BtnMain->Location = System::Drawing::Point(139, 21);
        this->BtnMain->Name = L"BtnMain";
        this->BtnMain->Size = System::Drawing::Size(120, 36);
        this->BtnMain->TabIndex = 0;
        this->BtnMain->Text = L"Start Main";
        this->BtnMain->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->BtnMain->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,   &Form1::BtnMain_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->BtnMain);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Package Analyzer";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void BtnMain_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
AfxBeginThread(ServerThread,0);
//while(_getch()!=27);
}
};
}
```

Comment: You *should* only interact with the UI on the UI thread. However, you can use the `Control.Invoke` method to do so on a background thread if you absolutely must. I recommend using something like the `BackgroundWorker` component instead, which helps automate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use .NET threads when using managed C++? Makes things much easier... You will, however, get exceptions when you access your controls from a different thread - you'll have to use `Invoke` to update controls from a thread.

**EDIT**
Well, I' can only write C#, but I'm sure you can easily convert this to C++:

```
private void BtnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    t.Start();
}

private void ThreadMethod(object state)
{
    // state would be set if you used ParameterizedThreadStart and t.Start(...) above


    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    ...

    // Set text of label on form. You must use this.Invoke, as otherwise
    // you'll run into an exception for changing controls from a different thread
    this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        label1.Text = "Hello";
    });
}
```

But it's not even required to do this in your case - use .NET TCP classes!

You should avoid mixing managed with unmanaged code and instead learn to use the abilities of the framework.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I totally missed the call to `AfxBeginThread` at the bottom of the posted code. I have no idea why you'd combine MFC with .NET.

Comment: I was developping a Console application and now I need to make it Windows form application. that's why I was using MFC. can you make me a code example of how to use .NET threads or  background worker in my case? I want to start the thread after the BtnMain is clicked and I want for example change the text of a label that is in the Form1

Comment: just another question: here it creates two classes, one for the Main and one for the Thread. but if I do this on a Windows app in the other class I does not see anymore this.label1.text. and if create both in a single class I can't call the thread function.http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx#Y746

Comment: Of course you do not see the private variables of your main class, as these are private to the class. You must design the thread according to your needs. If you want to access members of the class that starts the thread, don't create a separate class for the thread, but put the thread method in the class itself. Please note that it is not good practice to access controls from a thread!